# ubuntu 18.04 does not shutdown

Tags: shutdown

ubuntu 18.04 does not shutdown, it always restarts,
My lap is Dell Precision M4800, uses Nvidia drivers.
I tried to follow the instructions which I found here and elsewhere, but nothing to do.
I don't know how to manage this problem.
Please, help!